# Pointer arithmetics

Tags: c

not sure if the title is correct but I believe problem is there. I have this piece of code:

```
FILE_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION *Buffer;
Buffer = ExAllocatePoolWithTag (NonPagedPool, 4096, 'arK');
..<fill in data into the buffer>..
//Values here are: Buffer:0x81490000; NextEntryOffset:0x48
Buffer += Buffer->NextEntryOffset;
//Values here are: Buffer:0x81491440; NextEntryOffset:0x0
```

Problem is that instead of simple adding, the last code line performs multiplying. The new Buffer value should be (or at least I would wish it to be:) 81490048 but is 81491440 (81490000+48*48). Can anyone explain me why?

PS: I checked all the values using Windbg. Compiled using VS11, last code line is really translated into imul instruction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how pointer arithmetic works in C. Adding 'X' to a pointer actually means adding the size of the pointee X times to the starting memory location.

I think you can probably cast to a temporary `char *` and back, but I can't think of a reason.

Comment: Got it, so basicly I only need to treat it as a number. Casting to char* did the trick (originally I wanted BYTE but its not defined in my headers). Driver is working fine now, damn shame I didnt find this when writing user mode apps :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have:

```
T *p;
p += n;
```

then this is (roughly) equivalent to:

```
T *p;
char *p2 = (char *)p;
p2 += n * sizeof(T);
p = (T *)p2;
```

In other words, the compiler effectively does multiplication for you.

Answer (score 1):

When you add an integer to a pointer, the value of the pointer increases by the value of the integer times the size of the type pointed to by the pointer. If `sizeof(FILE_DIRECTORY_INFORMATION)` is 48, then adding one to a pointer shifts it by 48, adding 2 - by 2*48, and so on.